# Auto create Jenkins job from source code repo - no jenkins interaction

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket, devops

I am looking to auto create jobs in jenkins upon pull request , branches, master push etc similar to what we do in Gitlab. My SCM is butbucket here.

I have so far setup docker based agent integration with Jenkins and butbucket, when I create a job and configure it to use repo it all works fine , but I just want to remove altogether a step of job creation in jenkins and want the workflow like this:

In butbucket source code repo to keep all pipeline configuration for and branch and tag to trigger Jenkins pipeline without touching Jenkins for job creation or any config creation. Just want to drive all via the script in code repo for pipeline .

Any recommendations or help for workflow would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer to my Question , hence listing the steps for very simple use case for how it would work.

Steps:

1. Go to bitbucket server repository to which you want to enable pull request based trigger. Add Post Recieve Hook to this repository "Webhook to Jenkins for Bitbucket Server" , Enable this hook to have connection to jenkins. Enabling this plugin will issue POST request to jenkins each time a new Pull request is opened.
2. On Jenkins Server this will work with Blue Ocean Pipeline which by default will pick the change for pull request branch and trigger the job on each pull request.
3. Blue Ocean pipeline will by default create multi branch pipeline job to work with bitbucket repository.